# Secure web service for raspberry pi

Tags: python, web-services, asp.net-web-api, raspberry-pi

I am planning on creating a web application which can communicate with a raspberry PI. The web application will expose some web services to the raspberry pi. The flow of the application is basically:

*Web application*

- A user creates a profile
- A user can register one or more raspberries to their profile.

  - **On the web application, the user enters the MAC address for the Raspberry he wants to register**
  - **The user receives a new GUID for this raspberry**
- A user can upload content (i.e. a string)
- A user can uniquely assign the uploaded content to each of his/her registered raspberry devices.

*Raspberry PI Python application*

- **On a Python GUI, the user writes the generated GUID by the web application**
- **The raspberry calls the application's web service by sending it's registered GUID**
- The raspberry receives the information assigned to it.

However, my issue is that I wish to have the web services as secure as possible. This is not the case, as any user who knows the GUID of a device can make the call to the web service and get the same response as the raspberry would. Do you have any ideas to make this more secure?

Answer (score 0):

As far as  I Know, Why not use OAuth 2.0 for this purpose?

Instead of just passing the GUID, try to follow the OAuth 2.0 Protocol to communicate for the web services provided by your application.

Check out this website this might help you for getting started with OAuth 2.0
http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/oauth-20-the-good-the-bad-the-ugly--net-33216